# How to check if string exist in js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array in js, and want user to check if his product number exist in array. Code is:

```
    var arr = ['3bktzgo4',
'2ltold4k',
'l4u93l4r'];

function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == input) {
    alert("congratulations! Product code found! Your product is original!");
      return;
    }
  }
   alert("Product code not found! Your product is counterfeit!");
};

<div>
<button onclick="beginhere()">Search</button>
<input id='Input'>
</div>
```

Comment: `Code is:` What code?

Comment: I think you forgot something...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html !DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script>
var arr = ['3bktzgo4',
'2ltold4k',
'l4u93l4r'];

function check() {
  var productNumber = document.getElementById("productNumberId").value;
  console.log(productNumber);
  if(arr.indexOf(productNumber) != -1)
     return alert("congratulations! Product code found! Your product is original!");
  return alert("Product code not found! Your product is counterfeit!");
};
</script>
<div>
<button onclick="check()">Search</button>
<input id='productNumberId'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have created this snippet and would like you to know what mistakes or changes you need to make in your code.

1. Do not use words like "input" for variable names or ids, use words that can describe the value it stores.
2. The "check" function was never called and it should have replaced the "beginhere" function since this function was never defined.
3. You did not enclose your javascript code inside the `<script>` tag (read more about the important [tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp) in HTML).
4. Read about the useful functions in javascript like "indexOf", "splice", "push", "pop", etc that can help reduce your code or/and complexity.